# redux saga deleting functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I am working on React/Redux application, I have to delete user address, I am using redux saga as a middleware, the functionality is working fine, but the issue is after deleting address the request is not entering **deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess(in saga.js file)**, it is entering only **deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId** and **deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdFailure**(have checked in redux developer tools), can any one help me to sort out this issue,

My all functionality and screenshot of redux developer tools is given below

Action File

```
/* Delete an address for a buyer */
const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId =
    (buyerId: string, addressId: string, address: Object, params: string) => ({
        type: Types.DELETE_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID_ADDRESS_ID,
        buyerId,
        addressId,
        address,
        params,
    });

const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess =
    (buyerId: string, addressId: string, address: Object, params: string) => ({
        type: Types.DELETE_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID_ADDRESS_ID_SUCCESS,
        buyerId,
        addressId,
        address,
        params,
    });

const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdFailure =
    (errorMessage: Object) => ({
        type: Types.DELETE_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID_ADDRESS_ID_FAILURE,
        errorMessage,
    });
```

---

Saga file

```
/* Delete Buyers address */
function* deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId(action) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(
          api.account.deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId,
          action.buyerId,
          action.addressId,
          action.address,
          action.params
        );
        if (response.ok && response.data  && {}.hasOwnProperty.call(response.data, 'data')) {
            yield put(
          Actions.deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess(
              action.buyerId,
              action.addressId,
              response.data,
              action.address,
              action.params
          )
      );
        } else {
            yield put(Actions.deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdFailure(response.errorMessage));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(Actions.deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdFailure(error));
    }
}
function* watchDeleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId(): Generator<void, void, void> {
    yield takeLatest(Types.DELETE_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID_ADDRESS_ID, deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId);
}
```

---

Reducers

```
export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: true,
    successMessage: null,
    errorMessage: null,
});

export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => {
     const successMessage = I18n.getText('account.address-deleted', {}, 'Address deleted!');
     return {
        ...state,
        address: action.address,
        successMessage: successMessage,
      }
};

export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdFailure = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => ({
    ...state,
    errorMessage: action.errorMessage,
    isLoading: false,
});
```

---

redux developer tools view

[image]

---

Comment: Your program is going in catch or it is going in else?

Comment: yes, my program is going in the catch or else block, because their is null in response after deleting the user address, can you please tell me sollution for this, thanks in advance

Comment: If you are getting `null` response then it has to be a problem with your `call` function.

Comment: Yes I am getting null, but program is working fine (deleting address), i want to go program in success case,

Comment: You are calling `call` function which call your backend api to delete the addr. Are you sending `null` from backend after deleting the address? I mean what is the return value you are expecting from backend after addr. is deleted?

Comment: I am expecting some text like (Address deleted successfully), but in network tab response is null in data

Comment: So you are calling api to delete the address to backend. Your backend deletes the addr. and in return it gives null. So it is clearly the problem with your backend logic because your backend is returning `null` even after deleting the data, right?

Comment: Right, now you got it, I am calling API for deleting the address, backend is able to delete the address but gives null in response

Comment: I got your problem way before. What i am trying to say is that there is no problem with code you posted above. That is correct. The problem is with your `backend code` which is giving `null in response`.

Comment: Thanks prakash, than i will consult with my api developers, can you please upvote if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `if, else` part. Instead if the request is successful, merely call the success action within the `try` block itself. Otherwise inside your `catch` block invoke the failure action. That would do the job for you. Here's the sample code.

```
/* Delete Buyers address */
function* deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId(action) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(
          api.account.deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId,
          action.buyerId,
          action.addressId,
          action.address,
          action.params
        );
            yield put(
          Actions.deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess(
              action.buyerId,
              action.addressId,
              response.data,
              action.address,
              action.params
          )
      );
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(Actions.deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdFailure(error));
    }
}
function* watchDeleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId(): Generator<void, void, void> {
    yield takeLatest(Types.DELETE_ADDRESS_BY_BUYER_ID_ADDRESS_ID, deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId);
}
```